# Django Rest Framework create user custom serialization allows same email

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create users with the rest framework, but i can create more than one with the same email, how do i validate email taken?

this is my serializer code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoices = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        write_only_fields = 'password'
        read_only_fields = 'id'
        fields = ('id',
                  'username',
                  'email',
                  'password',
                  'invoices',
                  )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Ok, further reading on the [REST FRAMEWORK documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) , there is the "unique field" validator, by adding this, it works perfectly.

```
email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
```

So it would look like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
invoices = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = get_user_model().objects.create(
        email=validated_data['email'],
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    return user

class Meta:
    model = User
    write_only_fields = 'password'
    read_only_fields = 'id'
    fields = ('id',
              'username',
              'email',
              'password',
              'invoices',
              )
```

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set a unique=true constraint on the models email field instead of writing this yourself in the serializer.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#unique

Comment: true, but i need to get custom data from it (like the invoices fields) which is implemented from another model.

Answer (score -1):

***Copy and paste this code. Its working..***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoices = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        write_only_fields = 'password'
        read_only_fields = 'id'
        fields = ('id',
                  'username',
                  'email',
                  'password',
                  'invoices',
                  )

        def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.filter(email=validated_data['email'])
        if user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The email '" +
                                              validated_data['email'] +
                                              "' already exists")
        else:
            return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

The only change in your code is

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.filter(email=validated_data['email'])
    if user:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The email '" +
                                          validated_data['email'] +
                                          "' already exists")
    else:
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

In this function i get user details using email. If user exits and error Shows "The email xyz@xyz.com already exits.
Or if user does not exist then user is created.